# Android pass touch event to children

Tags: java, android, viewgroup

I have a `ViewGroup` container and some buttons inside it.
Layout looks like:

```
<MyCustomViewGroup>
    <Button>
</MyCustomViewGroup>
```

What i need is: detect touch event on my parent view and show/hide my Button by tap. And also i need my button click event.
What i have - if i get button click event, parent touch event doest not work, if i detect parent tap event, button click event is not working.

I have orerriden `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` for my parent view:

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            oldX = ev.getX();
            mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return true;
        } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true;
        } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            long timeDifference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastTime);
            float moveDifference = Math.abs((oldX - ev.getX()));
            if ((moveDifference <= 50) && (timeDifference <= 250L)) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onTap();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Cannot find how to combine onInterceptTouchEvent, onTouchEvent and dispatchTouchEvent to get it working.

Comment: tried to override `dispatchTouchEvent` in top parent?

Comment: why you don't simply set click listener ? as your touch event implementation is equivalent to click.